# How to count the kmer occurrence in FASTA file considering overlapping and reverse complement?

Tags: python, covid-19, sars-cov-2, k-mer, seqio

I am using count_overlap() for counting the kmers from Biopython .

Does it take the reverse complement of kmer into account?

I need to count reverse complement too

Comment: Hi @Lipsa, please provide a test example and your output together with any possible error messages. This appears certainly solvable. Is this method in Biopython?

Comment: I've had a guess at what I think the question should read

Comment: Thank you for your response Michael . However , this approach is getting very very slow when FASTA is of very large size and kmers are in millions. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot detail missing here, but at a guess could you try,

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq
for record in SeqIO.parse("ls_orchid.gbk", "genbank"):
    reversec = record.seq.reverse_complement())
    revcount = reversec.count_overlap('AT')
    print (revcount + count_overlap('AT'))
```

Essentially `count_overlap` only counts the forward strand if this is the Biopython method. Not debugged the above.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a C++ kmer counter](https://github.com/alexpreynolds/kmer-counter) I wrote for my own purposes. It can count canonical and reverse complement kmers from FASTA files up to length 31. Run `kmer-counter --help` or read the README for count options.

For longer kmers, you'd want to look at an approximation tool like [Jellyfish](https://github.com/gmarcais/Jellyfish).

Answer (score 0):

I would NOT recommend using biopython for a task like this. First, it's slow, but also it's really not necessary. There are several other existing tools optimised for exactly this purpose.

My favourite is [KMC](https://github.com/refresh-bio/KMC). It's very fast, and by default, it reports canonical kmers (Parameter `-b` would turn this off). So, assuming you have KMC installed, this is how you get all the kmers from a range of occurances (1 - 10000).

```
# just making a directory for temprary files
mkdir tmp

# building a kmer database with k = 21, 
# 16 cores and 
# up to 64GB of memory. 
# Counting occurances between 1 to 10000, 
# `-fa` specifies that the input is fasta, you can also input other formats
# the database name will be kmer_counts
# & saving temporary data to tmp directory; 
kmc -k21 -t16 -m64 -ci1 -cs10000 -fa my_seq.fasta kmer_counts tmp # run kmc

# extract kmers from the database in a text file
kmc_dump -ci1 -cx10000 kmer_counts kmer_k21.dump
```

Comment: I am lost here. Please help! I am using python 3. One vaex dataframe has 1million kmers and I want to check the count of these kmers in the FASTA file. How will I use KMC for this?

Comment: Yes, KMC can count kmer coverages directly from a fasta file. Just follow the code I posted there on how to use KMC to get kmers and their corresponding coverages.